# DELPHI - EOleException caused by grid with +1000 records

Tags: delphi, tms

I have the following problem:

I'm programming in DELPHI XE2 and using TDBAdvGrid by [TMS](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/). The grid gets filled from an SQL SERVER. The moment I want to load +1000 records at once I get the following error:

**First chance exception at $75CCC42D. Exception class EOleException with message 'There has occurred an unknown error'.**

When I click 'Break', the pointer stops in the following code:

```
function TDBAdvGrid.GetRecordCount: integer;

  function RowsInDataset: Integer;
  var
    cb: TBookMark;
    iseof, isbof: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := -1;
    if not CheckDataSet then
      Exit;

    FDataLink.DataSet.DisableControls;

    iseof := FDataLink.DataSet.Eof;
    isbof := FDataLink.DataSet.Bof;

    if isbof and iseof then
    begin
      Result := 0;
  //FMaxRows := 0;
    end
    else
      with FDataLink.DataSet do
      begin
        cb := GetBookMark;
        First;
        if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
          Result := MoveBy(100)
        else
          Result := MoveBy($7FFFFFFF) + 1; // <= programs breaks here!

        GotoBookMark(cb);
        FreeBookMark(cb);

    //FMaxRows := Result;
      end;

    if iseof then
      FDataLink.DataSet.Next;

    if isbof then
      FDataLink.DataSet.Prior;

    if FDataLink.DataSet.State = dsInsert then
      Result := Result + 1;

    FEmptyDataSet := Result = 0;
    FDataLink.DataSet.EnableControls;
  end;

//var
//  OldRecNo: integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if Assigned(FDataLink) then
    if Assigned(FDataLink.DataSet) then
      if FDataLink.DataSet.Active then
      begin
        FDoNotUpdateMe := true;

        if Assigned(FOnGetRecordCount) then
        begin
          FDataLink.DataSet.DisableControls;
          FOnGetRecordCount(self, Result);
          FEmptyDataSet := Result = 0;
          if (FloatingFooter.Visible) and PageMode and (FloatingFooter.FooterStyle = fsFixedLastRow) then
          begin
            if (Result = 0) then
              Inc(Result, 2)
            else
              Inc(Result);
          end;
          FDataLink.DataSet.EnableControls;
        end
        else
        begin
          Result := RowsInDataSet;
          if (FloatingFooter.Visible) and PageMode and (FloatingFooter.FooterStyle = fsFixedLastRow) then
          begin
            if (Result = 0) then
              Inc(Result, 2)
            else
              Inc(Result);
          end;
        end;
   { OldRecNo:= FDataLink.DataSet.RecNo;
    FDataLink.dataset.First;
    Result := FDataLink.dataset.MoveBy($FFFF);
    FDataLink.DataSet.RecNo:= OldRecNo; }
        FDoNotUpdateMe := false;
      end;
end;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I click 'Continue', I get in an infinite loop of this error. This error occurs only when I'm debug mode, when starting the exe outside Delphi and going to the form with the grid, there is no problem at all.
It also only occurs on my PC, my colleagues don't have this problem.

Updating TMS did not help.

I have mailed to TMS, but they say it's a problem from Delphi itself and they can't help me. Are they right?

At the moment I start the exe, load the grid, attach Delphi to the process and debug that piece of code I want. Not very handy but still better then nothing.

What can I do?

*We are looking to upgrade to XE7 or even 10 Seattle in near future, but hopefully this could be fixed soon*

**EDIT - SOME EXTRA INFO**

We recently made the step to DELPHI 10 SEATTLE, but the problem is still there. We also updated all TMS products.

I searched and found the mails I sent back in the day to TMS (couldn't find them the first them).
This is how the conversation went:

1. First I sent an e-mail explaining what was going, including screenshots (very similar to this SO-question)
2. I received an e-mail where they asked what dataset I'm using and if I could use the MoveBy instruction on the Dataset itself.
3. I tried what they asked and yes, I get the same error if I do `adoquery.moveby($FFFFFFF)`
4. They said it was unclear why I get that error and it was the first time someone reported this. This is where they said it's a fault in the dataset itself and they can't help it.

I have really no clue how to fix this...and I still don't understand why this only happens while debugging AND recordcount > 1000. Could it be something with paging?

@ kobik:

```
procedure TfrmGrondstoffen.MainDBGridGetRecordCount(Sender: TObject;
  var Count: Integer);
begin
     ShowMessage(inttostr(MainDBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount)); // gives the correct number
     ShowMessage(inttostr(qryGrondstoffen.RecordCount));  //gives the correct number
     ShowMessage(inttostr(Count)); // gives 0 all the time
end;
```

Also a bit weird I received 12 messageboxes instead of 3

Comment: Loading 1000 records from a Sql Server DB into a Delphi app should be no problem at all.  Try temporarily replacing the TMS grid with a standard TDBGrid.  Does that produced the same error? If it does, delete this q and post a new one containing **your** code that you use to get the data.  If it doesn't, then pester TMS.

Comment: I cant tell what `MoveBy($7FFFFFFF) + 1` does and why TMS used it.  Try to assign your own `OnGetRecordCount` event and return `YourDataSet.RecordCount`. but surly you need to ask TMS this question...

Comment: TMS offers free support to registered users through their own forums. Did you ask there first (where they are extremely familiar with their own code) before posting here?

Comment: It is possible that the grid is calling `OnGetRecordCount` multiple times. don't use `ShowMessage` to debug. simple return `Count := qryGrondstoffen.RecordCount` in your `MainDBGridGetRecordCount` event handler and see what happens...